# How to configure proper PostgreSQL results in Linux?

Tags: sql, postgresql, configuration

I am migrating from MySQL to PostgreSQL. With Postgres I can make a connection, which is perfect. After this, every query results a NULL pointer. What can be wrong?

I use Linuxmint 16, with Postgres 9.1 and libpq in eclipse C++ 4.7

```
m_connection = PQconnectStart ( dbname=restaurant user=mensfort password=zhongguo hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432 ) 
connected = PQstatus( m_connection); /* => result is CONNECTION_STARTED */

PGresult *res = PQexec( m_connection, "BEGIN");  /* -> Always a NULL pointer. */
ExecStatusType status = PQresultStatus(res);
```

I'm sure the database is available and the user exists with a proper password.

According to a friend, I changed the authentication:
Make changes to pg_hba.conf (authetification methods).

```
host    all         all       127.0.0.1/32       trust          # md5 -> trust
```

What else can I configure to make Postgres work on a local PC?

Comment: So what's in `status`?

Comment: Your friend was confused; If you have a working connection you don't need to mess with `pg_hba.conf` because if you connected successfully you're past that point already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend *reading the documentation* - start with [the libpq example program here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-example.html).

You'll notice that it tests `PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK` and if it's false, calls `PQerrorMessage(conn)` to get the error info.

You should never be caring what `res`'s value is. It's an opaque value to your program. In this case PostgreSQL is returning `NULL` to indicate an error, but you're supposed to use `PQresultStatus(res)` to check that, not test it directly. To get the error you query the connection object.

Comment: I have stopped with Postgres and started with MariaDB, which is 100% compatible with MySQL.